# Index out of bound of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, console

i have this two methods to look for an object in a list of products, but when i try to ask to select one object to see i get the  index out of bounds array(sorry that some of the code is in spanish)

```
  Public Producto BuscarProducto(int id,List<Producto> prod)
  {
        var productos = ObtenerProducto();
        var p = (from producto in productos
                 where producto.Id == id
                 select producto).First();


        return p;

    }



    public List<Producto> ObtenerProducto()
    {
        var datos = ObtenerLineas();
        List<Producto> productos = new List<Producto>();

        foreach (var item in datos)
        {

            string[] info = item.Split(',');

            Producto producto = new Producto
            {
                Id = int.Parse(info[0]),
                Nombre = info[1],
                Precio = double.Parse(info[2]),
                Categoria = info[3],
                Detalle = info[4]

            };
            productos.Add(producto);
        }
        return productos;
    }
```

Comment: What line does it happen and what did the debugger say about the problem? At least you’re not checking there’s enough elements in `info` so it’s easy to go out of bounds there

Comment: item you are splitting ... are you sure it has 5 elements?

Comment: The error is marked here  

Producto producto = new Producto
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(info[0]),
                    Nombre = info[1],
                    Precio = double.Parse(info[2]),
                    Categoria = info[3],
                    Detalle = info[4]

                };
                productos.Add(producto);

Comment: yes i have a list with 20 objects, each one has 5 atributes

Comment: well.. check that again and make sure each object has 4 commas and 5 elements. In a nutshell, index out of range means you are accessing element of an array that doesnt exist. If info only has 4 elements, then info[5] will give you out of bounds error

Comment: Make sure that there are four "," in the string that you are trying to split.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there are four "," in the string that you are trying to split.

Also it would be better to check if there are atleast 5 elements in the array. You could try replacing your Add code with this checking.

```
if (info != null && info.Length >= 5)
{
    Producto producto = new Producto
    {
        Id = int.Parse(info[0]),
        Nombre = info[1],
        Precio = double.Parse(info[2]),
        Categoria = info[3],
        Detalle = info[4]
    };
    productos.Add(producto);
}
```